# Is there any way to highlight text in a powerpoint presentation with Office.js

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to find a way to highlight a selected range or binding in a powerpoint presentation in a different color using the PowerPoint JS API, but haven't found anything.  Does any one know if this is possible with the PowerPoint API.  For reference I'm trying to do something like this but with powerpoint.run instead:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.
            var body = context.document.body;

            // Queue a commmand to clear the contents of the body.
            body.load("font");

            return context.sync().then(function () {
                // Queue a set of commands to change the font for each found item.
                body.font.color = 'black';
                body.font.underline = 'turquoise';
                return context.sync();
            })
                .catch(errorHandler);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, fine-grained formatting is not yet supported in PowerPoint by the Office JavaScript library.